# Why doesn't "grep *q1*" match anything?

Tags: git, shell, grep

I have a list of files using:

```
$git show commit:.data/path/to/file/

abc-2018-q1.csv
def-2019-q2.csv
the-2019-q1.csv
```

I am trying to do `$git show commit:.data/path/to/file/ | grep *q1*`

ie select only those files whose names contain "q1". However the step the step does not give any result.

How can I get the desired files containing "q1".

Comment: `grep` expects a regex, not a wildcard (and moreover, when you don't quote your argument, it's evaluated by the shell as a glob expression before grep even sees it). You want something like `git show commit:.data/path/to/file | grep -e 'q1'`.

Comment: BTW, you might consider [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) for questions that are more about command-line UNIX tooling than software development as such. Questions specific to git are certainly on-topic here, but grep isn't meaningfully "unique to software development".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select only those files whose names contain "q1". However the step the step does not give any result.

grep finds patterns, and `q1` is a perfectly fine pattern on its own.

```
git show commit:.data/path/to/file/ | grep q1
```

Comment: Just using q1 gives the answer. I should have mentioned it in my question. However I specifically wanted to use wildcards here. Anyway I have accepted your answer though.

Comment: The point is that you don't use wildcards in grep like you do when specifying filenames in the shell.  If you're just searching for the string "q1" appearing somewhere on the line, then that's all you need to put for your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

That command seems wrong,
 try this:

```sh
git show commit:.data/path/to/file | grep "q1"
```